# Deleting X lines from a dynamically allocated array in C by using a function?

Tags: c, arrays, vector

I have a vector V with lines to be deleted. I need to use functions for:
- reading and writing the matrix A where a list of firms are stored
- reading and writing V, where the lines to be deleted are.
- deleting the lines from A, where the X lines are stored as values in V.

My problems:

1. How do I use a function to read the X lines to be deleted and store them in V? I can do it just fine in main(), but I can't figure out how to do the reading in a function.
2. What am I doing wrong in the stergere() function? If I replace the elements in the X line with 0 and then ignore said elements when I write the matrix after deleting, it works fine, but that's not optimal. I want to actually delete said elements so the overall size of the matrix scales down as well.

ALSO, if you could point me in the right direction with not having to ask the user first how many lines s/he wants deleted, that would be great. Right now, I have to use a variable that will store the number of lines to be deleted (read from keyboard), then dynamically allocate V with the size read from keyboard. Is there any way to have the user constantly read X values until a certain key is pressed, and store those elements in V? Sort of like a vector::push_back in c++?

Thank you, here's the code:

```
// ConsoleApplication76.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

// alocarea matricei B in memorie in functie de numarul de linii de sters din vectorul x
void alocare(float*** b, int* y, int m, int *n, int x){
    *y = m - x;
    (*b) = (float**)malloc((*y)*sizeof(float*));
    for (int i = 0; i<(*y); i++)
        (*b)[i] = (float*)malloc((*n)*sizeof(float));
}

//citirea matricei A
void citireA(float*** a, int *m, int *n){
    printf("Nr linii m al matricei a   : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &(*m));
    printf("Nr coloane n al matricei a : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &(*n));
    (*a) = (float**)malloc((*m)*sizeof(float*));
    for (int i = 0; i < (*m); i++)
        (*a)[i] = (float*)malloc((*n)*sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < (*m); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < (*n); j++){
        printf("a[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
        scanf_s("%f", &(*a)[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// afisarea matricei A
void afisareA(float **a, int m, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i<m; i++){
        printf("%d: ", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf(" %5.2f ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// citirea vectorului V
void citireV(int** v, int *x){
    printf("Numar de linii de sters: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &(*x));
    *(v) = (int*)malloc(*(x)*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < *(x); i++){
        printf("Linia ce va fi stearsa: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &(*v)[i]);
    }
}

// afisarea vectorului V
void afisareV(int* v, int x){
    printf("\nLiniile ce vor fi sterse: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        printf("%d ", v[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

bool nullT(int m, int x){
    if (m == x){
        printf("Matricea rezultata va fi nula\n");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// functie pentru a sterge valorile care se afla de mai multe ori in vectorul v. in caz ca aceeasi linie
// se afla de 2 ori in vectorul V, in matricea A nu va putea fi gasita linia v[i] in a doua iteratie, cauzand un crash.
void stergereDup(int** v, int *x){
    for (int i = 0; i < (*x)-1; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < (*x); j++)
        if ( (*v)[i] == (*v)[j] ) {
            for (int ii = i; ii < (*x) - 1; ii++)
                (*v)[ii] = (*v)[ii + 1];
            (*x)--;
        }
    }

// afisarea matricei B
void afisareB(float **b, int y, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i<y; i++){
        printf("%d: ", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf(" %5.2f ", b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// functia principala de stergere a linillor v[i] din matricea A
void stergere(float** a, float*** b, int* v, int* y, int *m, int n, int x){
    int kb = 0;
    int q = 0;
    bool test = false;
    while (q != *m){
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        if (v[i] == q) test = true;
        if (!test){
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                (*b)[kb][i] = a[q][i];
            }
            kb++;
            printf("\n");
        }
        test = false;
        q++;
    }
}


int main(){
    float** a;
    float** b;
    int* v;
    int m, n, x, y;

    citireA(&a, &m, &n);
    afisareA(a, m, n);

    citireV(&v, &x);
    stergereDup(&v, &x);
    afisareV(v, x);

    if (nullT(m, x)) return 0;
    else {
        alocare(&b, &y, m, &n, x);
        stergere(a, &b, v, &y, &m, n, x);
        afisareB(b, y, n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Phew! There is a *lot* of unnecessary`*` in there. For example `stergere(... int *m, ...)` does not alter the `m` passed. And in `citireM(... int *m, ...)` the statement `scanf_s("%d", &(*m));` would be so much easier to follow as `scanf_s("%d", m);`.

Comment: _delete lines_ sounds like you want to see spreadsheet behavior, i.e. when a row is deleted, it all goes away, and another row comes up and replaces it.  Arrays in C do not work that way.  Once you create space for an array dynamically, you can copy values from the space by navigating the pointers and copy to another space.  Or you can initialize all values in a _row_, or a _column_ to `""`, or `0`.  but  space cannot be _deleted_ from just a _row_ or _column_.

Comment: I know about the scanf_s, but since I'm just starting with dynamically allocated arrays I figured it would be easier for me to write it like that, even if they do sort of cancel out. I'm still trying to understand the concept!

Comment: @ryyker That's sort of how I wanted to do it. Is it not possible to sort of copy the X+1 line(X being the one to be deleted) to the X line, then subtract 1 from the total number of lines? Basically replace X line with X+1 and just somehow remove the last line?

Comment: Of course it's possible to do that. Remember to shift every other line after X as well.

Comment: Okay! So by using the 2 for sequnces in stergere(), shouldn't that be exactly what's needed? What am I doing wrong there? For some reason, that's the part that causes the program to crash.

Comment: `stergere` doesn't actually change the values of `a`, `m`, or `n`, so change its signature to accept a `float **`. Change every `*(a)[][]` to `a[][]`, (and `*m` to `m`, and `*n` to `n`) and call it as `stergere(a, v, m, n, x)`.

Comment: `*(a)[i][j]` means "the thing pointed at by the thing found j indexes away from the thing found i indexes away from a". You meant `(*a)[i][j]`.

Comment: @AustinMullins I was under the impression that m will be changed because after each iteration and copying line x+1 to x, after subtracting 1 from m, the final m value would change. The program works now, but those lines that were supposed to be deleted are still taking double space, I just have to show on screen by calling the afisare() function with m-x elements, because the number of elements in the V vector will be the number of lines to be deleted.

Comment: You _could_ change m and pass it as a pointer. You didn't though. Just delete the rows you don't use.

Comment: @AustinMullins I've figured it out. It works fine now. I'll update the main post with the final code. I allocated another array called B with the total size of m-x lines(lines of A - total lines to be deleted), then simply copied the lines from A that weren't found in the V vector to B. Also added another function to check if there are any duplicate numbers in the V vector, since if there were any they would cause the program to crash. Pretty happy with the outcome, thank you so much!

Comment: Please don't be a [three-star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: My teacher is forcing us to use the three stars when modifying arrays in functions. From what I understood, you have ** because it's an array, and another * because you're modifying its values within said function, and those values need to be returned to the array in main(). Is there a better way to modify an array in a function without using *** ?

Comment: If you solved the problem, reduce the code in your question to just the problematic part and add the solution as an answer.